# Recursive copy part of xml and apply templates on the copy

Tags: xml, xslt, recursion

I have next XML.
next problem. I made templetes for children of weneedit node. 
and i need remove all exclude weneedit and his children.
I can't apply template and make recursive copy together.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <list>
    <element>
      <subelement>123</subelement>
    </element>
    <element>
    <subelement>
      <weneedit>
        <andit>
          <helpfultext>
          </helpfultext>
        </andit>
      </weneedit>
    </subelement>
    </element>

  </list>
  <tag>
  <rt>321</rt>
  </tag>
</root>
```

I have tried do like that

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:n="http://www.example.com/example/example.xsd" >
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="n:weneedit">
    <xsl:copy-of select="parent::node()"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but works one or other template not together

i want to get something like this

```
<subelement>
  <weneedit>
    <andit>
      <helpfultext>it was edited</helpfultext>
    </andit>
  </weneedit>
</subelement>
```

Comment: What is the expected result of your example input?

Comment: If there is a namespace in your input document (your second template suggests there is), then include it in the question. Also, your input XML is not well-formed because `tag` is not properly closed.

Comment: Can you confirm that is exactly the output you need? You don't actually want the `root` and `list` elements copied too? Thanks!

Comment: In that case, can you please edit your question to show the precise output. Otherwise you might get an answer that is not precisely what you needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I understand your problem. The folowing stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="list/element/subelement[weneedit]"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will result in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<subelement>
  <weneedit>
    <andit>
      <helpfultext/>
    </andit>
  </weneedit>
</subelement>
```

You can add additional templates to handle the included nodes, e.g. `<helpfultext>`.

Note that this assumes there's only one `<subelement>` that contains `<weneedit>`; otherwise your result will have more than one root element, which is not allowed in XML.